# How to get time_in and time_out attendance using mysql code

Tags: mysql

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `raws_attendance` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_reg` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `raws_attendance` (`id`, `no_reg`, `date_time`, `time`) VALUES
(13, '2019069', '2020-05-04 07:15:00', '07:15:00'),
(14, '2019069', '2020-05-04 21:15:00', '21:15:00'),
(15, '2019069', '2020-05-05 03:15:00', '03:15:00'),
(16, '2019069', '2020-05-05 04:15:00', '04:15:00'),
(17, '2019069', '2020-05-05 07:15:00', '07:15:00'),
(18, '2019069', '2020-05-05 21:15:00', '21:15:00'),
(19, '2019070', '2020-05-04 07:25:00', '07:25:00'),
(20, '2019070', '2020-05-04 21:25:00', '21:25:00'),
(21, '2019070', '2020-05-05 03:35:00', '03:35:00'),
(22, '2019070', '2020-05-05 04:25:00', '04:25:00'),
(23, '2019070', '2020-05-05 07:55:00', '07:55:00'),
(24, '2019070', '2020-05-05 21:55:00', '21:55:00');
```

I want to make a value in `time_in` and `time_out` field

In `time_in`, employee had a time value range `06:15:00 AM` until `11:59:00 AM` and for `time_out` employee had a time value range `12:00:00 PM` until `06:14:00 AM`

But I want make the `time_out` field become double for first range is `12:00:00 PM` until `11:59:00 PM` and for the second range is `12:00:00 AM` until `06:14:00 AM`

For the condition if the `time_out` had a double time, it will be executed the highest time

For example, if the employee had absent `time_out` in `09:00:00 PM` and then the employee get absent `time_out` again in time `01:00:00 AM` so for the final `time_out` is `01:00:00 AM`,

But I had some problem when I want to make that condition. The result is that the time does not blend with the `time_in` that is on that day but rather makes a new day and makes `time_in` and `time_out` itself, and that causes `time_in` on that day to be a null value

For result table query :

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|no_reg   | in_out  |  attendance_date      |        time_in        | time_out           |
|---------|---------|-----------------------|-----------------------|--------------------|
|2019069  | IN      | 04.05.2020 00:00:00   |  04.05.2020 07:15:00  | 04.05.2020 21:15:00|
|2019069  | OUT     |       NULL            |          NULL         | 05.05.2020 04:15:00|
|2019069  | IN      | 05.05.2020 00:00:00   |  05.05.2020 07:15:00  | 05.05.2020 21:15:00|
|2019070  | IN      | 04.05.2020 00:00:00   |  04.05.2020 07:25:00  | 04.05.2020 21:25:00|
|2019070  | OUT     |       NULL            |          NULL         | 05.05.2020 04:25:00|
|2019070  | IN      | 05.05.2020 00:00:00   |  05.05.2020 07:55:00  | 05.05.2020 21:55:00|
|---------|---------|-----------------------|-----------------------|--------------------|
```

For Query MYSQL :

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @no_reg = NULL;

SELECT 
   `no_reg`,
CASE
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '06:15:00' AND '11:59:00' THEN "IN"
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '23:59:00' THEN "OUT"
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:14:00' THEN "OUT"
END in_out,
DATE(MAX(CASE WHEN  CASE
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '06:15:00' AND '11:59:00' THEN "IN"
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '23:59:00' THEN "OUT"
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:14:00' THEN "OUT"
END = 'IN' THEN `date_time` END)) AS attendance_date,
MAX(CASE WHEN CASE
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '06:15:00' AND '11:59:00' THEN "IN"
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '23:59:00' THEN "OUT"
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:14:00' THEN "OUT"
END = 'IN' THEN `date_time` END) AS time_in,
MAX(CASE WHEN CASE
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '06:15:00' AND '11:59:00' THEN "IN"
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '23:59:00' THEN "OUT"
  WHEN `time` BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:14:00' THEN "OUT"
END = 'OUT' THEN `date_time` END) AS time_out
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
     @row_number:=CASE WHEN @no_reg = `no_reg` THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 0 END AS rn,
     TRUNCATE(@row_number / 2, 0) AS rn_rgp,
     @no_reg:=`no_reg`
  FROM raw_attendance
  ORDER BY no_reg, date_time
) t
GROUP BY t.`no_reg`, t.rn_rgp;
```

I hope everyone understands what I explained, I put link to sql editor online in bellow :

[Rextester SQL Online](https://rextester.com/UELUS69596)

Comment: something like that? Thank you for your suggest

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, is the following intermediate result valid:

```
SELECT *
     , CASE WHEN time >= '06:15:00' AND time < '12:00:00' THEN 'in' ELSE 'out' END in_out 
  FROM raws_attendance;
+----+---------+---------------------+----------+--------+
| id | no_reg  | date_time           | time     | in_out |
+----+---------+---------------------+----------+--------+
| 13 | 2019069 | 2020-05-04 07:15:00 | 07:15:00 | in     |
| 14 | 2019069 | 2020-05-04 21:15:00 | 21:15:00 | out    |
| 15 | 2019069 | 2020-05-05 03:15:00 | 03:15:00 | out    |
| 16 | 2019069 | 2020-05-05 04:15:00 | 04:15:00 | out    |
| 17 | 2019069 | 2020-05-05 07:15:00 | 07:15:00 | in     |
| 18 | 2019069 | 2020-05-05 21:15:00 | 21:15:00 | out    |
| 19 | 2019070 | 2020-05-04 07:25:00 | 07:25:00 | in     |
| 20 | 2019070 | 2020-05-04 21:25:00 | 21:25:00 | out    |
| 21 | 2019070 | 2020-05-05 03:35:00 | 03:35:00 | out    |
| 22 | 2019070 | 2020-05-05 04:25:00 | 04:25:00 | out    |
| 23 | 2019070 | 2020-05-05 07:55:00 | 07:55:00 | in     |
| 24 | 2019070 | 2020-05-05 21:55:00 | 21:55:00 | out    |
+----+---------+---------------------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is the query result above a tool to determine the range between time_in and time_out?

Comment: It's just a starting point to check that I understand the rules, but it might become part of a solution

Comment: Your answer is part of the solution to resolve this problem, I already made it the same as you did, but I am confused how to make a higher time, if the results of time_out above at 12 pm